# Guttural pronunciation of {h} in American English

Tags: phonology, accent

I'm not a native speaker. I've noticed that some Americans pronounce {h} as a guttural sound sometimes. Is this a documented feature of American English?

Examples:

- https://youtu.be/j2I9LpDF708?t=7 (the first time she says *horribly*)
- https://youtu.be/m7T2fliH8go?t=560 (*heart*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minor phonetic tendency in US dialects that I have not see studied, but have observed a few times. There is an allophonic rule where /h/ becomes a pharyngeal before back low and mid vowels. I know one speaker from NYC who does this – it tends to happen when the word is stressed. That covers the two Youtube examples as well (the speakers otherwise have regular [h]). I believe Woody Allen has this feature in his speech, at least in movies.

Answer (score 0):

You hear it also from British (Received pronunciation) speakers in emphatic or deliberate speech. It sounds very much like the Arabic pharyngeal ح .